# xampp not work like server

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to save browser `cookies` into text file by using `curl`, but `xampp` does not work as a server.

Please help me.How can I fix this? If I need to modify any setting need to have `XAMPP` working as a server.

This is my `PHP` code.

```
$cookie = 'myname.txt'
$ch = curl_init();
 //// Some code then get cookies == $cookie
}
file_get_contents($cookie); // This code create myname.txt file on server
 // but its show error in xampp no file directory found
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` does not create a file.. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php vs. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php.

Comment: i know but when i use this on live site it will create a file. well tell me any other way to save cookies into txt file thanks

Comment: This would never create a file on any server. The file was probably already there. Use the latter link in my first comment.

Comment: hmm i understand. just simply tell me how can i save cookie.txt file into directory.

Comment: The second like I provided has everything you need.

Comment: i try but its write text file name not cookies

Comment: Parameter 1 is the name, 2 is the content. What do you mean? Update the questions code if you are using new code and explain what happens now.

Comment: i know Parameter 1 is the name is okay, but 2 is the content is $cookie = 'myname.txt'  i fill this text with curl cookies its work on server fine but not working on xampp

Comment: Update the question with the new code